# How to run "if not exist" when the path contains several spaces

Tags: batch-file, file-exists

I have to use this command to create a folder if it doesn't exist:

```
if not exist "C:\Users\Lo\Docs" mkdir C:\Users\Lo\Docs\1
```

... but for a path containing a several spaces
C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1

I have tried all of these but none of them worked:

1)

```
if not exist ""C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1" mkdir C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1
```

2)

```
if not exist "^"C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1" mkdir C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1
```

3)

```
set "PATH=C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1;%PATH%"
if not exist "%PATH%" mkdir C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1
```

Comment: Don't you think maybe you should try putting quotes around the second path too?  ... `mkdir "C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1"`

Comment: Thanks a lot @musefan. If you write this in an answer, I will upvote you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to put the quotes around the second path too...

```
if not exist "C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1" mkdir "C:\Users\Lo Ti\Docs 2015\1"
```